# Diagnostics for multinomial and ordinal regression models

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution, ordered-logit, diagnostic

In the case of a binary outcome and a number of explanatory variables, **logistic regression** can be used and a number of diagnostic tools can be applied to assess the *relative* (e.g. AIC, if one wishes to compare 2 models) or *absolute goodness-of-fit* (e.g. plotting Pearson residuals, and watching out for trends, homoskedasticity) of the model.

In the case of a categorical outcome, similar diagnostic tools of *relative goodness-of-fit* can be used using **multinomial and ordinal regression**, but how about the absolute goodness-of-fit?

So far all I could do when using such models was to plot expected vs. observed probabilities. 
Looking at the behaviour of the residuals does not seem to make sense given that for each level they will be correlated to another / the other levels...

Is there any other approach that can be used to assess these models properly? I have looked for this information for a while and cannot seem to find anything better than observed vs. predicted...